# How to reason about the combinatorial term "$n$ choose $k$" (i.e., $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$)

Tags: combinatorics

The combinatorial number is the number of picking $k$ unordered outcomes out of $n$ possible choices. In that setting, we have a set $A$ with $|A|=n$ and the combinatorial numbers is just really the number of subsets $S\subset A$ with $|S| = k$.

This number is

$$\binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!},$$

but how can we reason about this? How can we derive this formula? I've seem some people reasoning about this in the following way: the number of ways to choose permutations with size $k$ among $n$ objects is

$$n(n-1)\cdots (n-k-1) = \dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)(n-k)\cdots 1}{(n-k)(n-k-1)\cdots 1} = \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!},$$

then we have to divide by $k!$ to disconsider the order. Why is that? Why dividing by $k!$ we get the number of subsets of $A$ with size $k$?

Comment: "Why dividing by $k!$?" : Because there is k! way to arrange with order the elements of a set with k elements.

Comment: "How can we derive this formula?" and "Why dividing by $k!$ we get the number of subsets of $A$ with size $k$?" are two *very* different questions--you may want to make it clearer *exactly* what you are asking. The former question, the one I tried to answer, is more interesting, but some people may think your question really concerns the latter (as pointed out by one answer and a comment already).

Comment: For what it's worth, the first proof that I saw was to show that $n! = \binom nk k! (n-k)!$, which I think was an excellent way to do the proof without thinking about double-counting or equivalence relations or any of that nonsense. But as Magic notes, the question of how you'd come up with the formula is very different.

Comment: Just as a reference: these numbers are called [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), since they appear as coefficients in the expansion of $(x+y)^n$.

Comment: I just added a more combinatorial way of looking at it. Hopefully that clarifies things somewhat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Comment:** I'll outline one way of thinking about the equation in question and a way of proving it that will possibly shed some insight. Induction is not the best or most efficient method of proof here, but it is slightly interesting that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ can be proved using induction where Pascal's Rule is actually applied at the very end of the proof, and **the proof also gives justification for the combinatorial terminology "$n$ choose $k$" represented by $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.**

---

**Patterns:**

- **Lemma 1:** A set with $n$ elements has $n$ subsets containing exactly one element whenever $n\geq 1, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- **Lemma 2:** A set with $n$ elements has $n(n-1)/2$ subsets containing exactly two elements whenever $n\geq 2, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- **Lemma 3:** A set with $n$ elements has $n(n-1)(n-2)/6$ subsets containing exactly three elements whenever $n\geq 3, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

All three lemmas can be proved rather easily using induction. It is interesting to note the *pattern* that emerges in Lemmas 1-3. It appears that we can make a conjecture as to what the number of $k$-element subsets will be for a set with $n$ elements.

---

**Theorem:** A set with $n$ elements has
$$
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}
$$
subsets containing exactly $k$ elements whenever $0\leq k\leq n$, and $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof.* When $n=0$, the only possible choice for $k$ is $k=0$, and when $n=k=0$, $\binom{0}{0} = 1$. This is true because the number of zero-element sets in a zero-element set is 1 (i.\,e., $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$). Lemmas 1-3 satisfy the cases when $n=1,2,3$, respectively. The proof proceeds by induction on $n$ of the statement $P(n):$ There are $\binom{n}{k}$ distinct $k$-element sets in a set with $n$ elements for every $k$ satisfying $0 \leq k \leq n$.

Assume $P(\ell)$ is true for some $\ell \geq 3, \ell \in \mathbb{Z}$, and let $M$ be a set with $\ell+1$ elements. To show that $P(\ell) \rightarrow P(\ell+1)$, we must show that the number of $k$-element sets in $M$ is $\binom{\ell+1}{k}$ for every $k$ satisfying $0 \leq k \leq \ell+1$. When $k=0, \binom{\ell+1}{0}=1$, and when $k=\ell+1, \binom{\ell+1}{\ell+1} = 1$. Let $k$ satisfy $1 \leq k \leq \ell$, and fix some $\alpha \in M$. The number of $k$-element sets in $M$ that contains $\alpha$ is the number of sets with $k-1$ elements in $M \setminus \{ \alpha \}$; since $\left\vert{M \setminus \{ \alpha \}}\right\vert = \ell$, there are $\binom{\ell}{k-1}$ such sets by the inductive hypothesis. The number of sets with $k-1$ elements that do not contain $\alpha$ is $\binom{\ell}{k}$, also by the inductive hypothesis. Using Pascal's Identity, the number of $k$-element sets in $M$ is $\binom{\ell}{k-1}+\binom{\ell}{k} = \binom{\ell+1}{k}$.

Thus, the statement $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the Theorem holds by induction. $\blacksquare$

---

**Added:** The notation $\binom{n}{k}$ is sometimes introduced in combinatorics by first introducing the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol), $n^{\underline{k}}$. An explanation of the above Theorem with a more combinatorial flavor (since your question is tagged `combinatorics`) may briefly proceed as follows: Let $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For $k\leq n$, the injection $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}\to A$ is a $k$-element permutation. The number of $k$-element permutations of a set of size $n$ is given by
$$
n^{\underline{k}}=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot(n-k+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}.
$$
Since $\binom{n}{k}$ is by definition the number of $k$-element subsets of size $n$ and there are $k!$ ways to order a set of size $k$, we know that $n^{\underline{k}}=\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!$, and this implies that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $n$ ways to choose the first element, then $n-1$ ways (one element is already removed) to choose the second element and .. $n-k+1$ ways (since the previous $k-1$ elements are already removed) to choose the last element (here the order the elements are chosen is **important**, since it matters which element is chosen first, second and so on). In other words, this procedure counts $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ as **two distinct combinations** of two elements. So it **counts all $k!$ permutations of the same chosen elements as distinct** (see below).

So this number is $n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times .. \times (n-k+1)$  $$= \frac{n \times (n-1) \times .. \times 1}{(n-k) \times (n-k-1) \times .. \times 1} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$ 
(by the definition of factorial)

Since order does not matter these $k$ numbers can be permuted in $k!$ ways (similar reasoning as above), so we have to **divide by this number to discard the permutations**. So the final result is:

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = {n \choose k}$$

To elaborate a little on this by an example, suppose we have the items $(a,b,c,d)$ and we wamt to choose two of them where order does not matter (i.e count both $(a,d)$ and $(d,a)$ **as the same combination**, meaning discard permutations).

We have $4$ ways to choose the first element which can be anyone lets say $a$. Then we have $3$ ways to choose the second element which lets say is $d$. But the same process can also count this scenario: the first element is $d$ and the second is $a$.

Another way to see the combinatorial coefficient (where order does not matter) is this:

> We have $n$ ways to choose the first element **and $k$ ways to place
>   it in any position** $1..k$, then $n-1$ ways (one element is already
>   removed) to choose the second element **and $k-1$ ways to place it in
>   another position** (one position is already taken) and .. so on

Comment: You might want to explicitly mention that, in multiplying $n\cdot (n - 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n - k)$, the order is inherently important: The tuples $(4, 6, 7)$ and $(6, 7, 4)$ would each be counted, for example. *This* is the reason why "disordering" is necessary, and what I assume is really the core of the OP's question.

Comment: @pjs36, yeap, thanks updating

Answer (score 2):

This might be verbose but bear with me, imagine you have a bag with $10$ marbles and you want to figure out all the ways you can pick the $10$ marbles out of the bag (so lists of 10 marbles in different combinations), for the sake of clarity imagine every one of those marbles have a unique color. In your first choice you have $10$ different marbles to choose from, let's say you pick pink, now you have $9$ different choices, but what if you originally picked orange, now you still have $9$ different choices. What this shows is that for every first marble you choose you have 9 more to go for, or in other words $10\times 9$ choices.  If we continue for the third marble we have 8 possible choices after we removed the second marble, so again we have $9\times 8$ choices but remember we had 10 groups of choices from the beginning, so in total we have $10\times 9\times 8$ choices. This goes on until you have 1 marble left in which case you have a total choice of $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times \cdots \times 1 = 10!$ possible choices for our bag of 10 marbles. Now let's say we actually only want to pick 4 marbles, not all 10. That means out of the possible $10!$ choices for all $10$ we only get $10\times 9\times 8 \times 7$ or equivalently:
$$\frac{10!}{(10-4)!} = \frac{10!}{6!} = 7\times 8\times 9\times 10$$
Possible choices. What if though, we don't care about the order of choice, so the marbles we do pick, we can label them as $R,G,B,Y$ order does not matter. So, $R,G,B,Y$ is equivalent to $R,B,G,Y$. So, if want to choose $4$ marbles from our bag of $10$ and we don't care about the arrangement of our elements we need to divide it by $4!$ which represents our number of ways to arrange $4$ elements, hence:

$$\frac{10!}{4!\cdot(10-4)!} = 210$$